# How to redirect tfdbg dumping directory

Tags: tensorflow

By default, `tfdbg` dumps saved tensors to `/tmp`, but in my case, `/tmp` is mount in `/root`, `/root` has only several G's space, running the example debug is not a problem, but when debugging large network, for which in one run will generate tensors that exceeds 10 G's memory, it would prompts space not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Answered in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/16867

The constructors LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession and LocalCLIDebugHook both have a keyword argument called dump_root, which allows you to specify where to dump the debug data.

See:

[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession#**init**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession#__init__)

[https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/LocalCLIDebugHook#**init**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tfdbg/LocalCLIDebugHook#__init__)